# Why isn't curl getting the session id?

Tags: oauth2, session, curl

curl -v https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=" -d "client_secret=" -d "username=" -d "password="

I've tried this with instance name instead of **test** or **login**. I also tried with my **security token** appended to the end of the password.

I'm 100% positive that I've using the client_id, client_secret, and username for the sandbox that I'm testing with.

**response:**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 96.43.145.28...
* Connected to test.salesforce.com (96.43.145.28) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: test.salesforce.com
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: test.salesforce.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 214
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 214 out of 214 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Tue, 11 Nov 2014 14:28:04 GMT
< Set-Cookie: BrowserId=SIIHl7AKTn2BgoK5jwajtg;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 10-Jan-2015 14:28:04 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host test.salesforce.com left intact
{"error_description":"authentication failure","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen client id's and some passwords which need to be urlencoded/escaped to work well with curl.

Maybe you should try the --data-urlencode option (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060093/special-characters-like-and-in-curl-post-data )

Example usage would be:
curl -v https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" --data-urlencode "client_id=" -d "client_secret=" -d "username=" --data-urlencode 'password='